# PYSPARK: add leading zero with condition

Tags: pyspark

I have a list of IDs with different patterns, some of them have 4 characters, others 9 characters, etc.

I need to add a leading 0 only to the IDs with 9 characters and not to affect other items.

With this code I am adding '0' to all items in the list:

`df = df.withColumn('ID', F.lpad(F.col('ID'), 10, '0'))`

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got it:

`df.withColumn('RESULT', F.when(F.length(df['ID']) == 9, F.lpad(df['ID'], 10, '0')).otherwise(df['ID'])).show(100, False)`